# Module not found, Error package path ./swiper.min.css is not exported

Tags: web-deployment, package.json, modulenotfounderror, swiper.js, react-swiper

Module not found: Error: Package path ./swiper.min.css is not expoot exported from package D:\Frontend\React\movie-app\node_mswiper rted fromodules\swiper (see exports field in D:\Frontend\React\movieles\swirts field-app\node_modules\swiper\package.json)

I'm getting this error and cant deploy the project. I am able to see it in localhost. Please help me out..

Comment: hi, did you find the answers to question ?

Answer (score 4):

As the documentation says:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/react/slides

There are various different ways of importing the Swiper .css depending on what technologies you are using.

This is how it is imported in the documentation example

`import 'swiper/swiper.min.css';`

*But just below that it says*

> Not using Create React App? You can import the Swiper CSS from swiper/css instead.

So in my case where I am developing my app in Ionic, my import would look like this:

**`import 'swiper/css';`**

There are other options as well depending on how you are styling your sheets.

> For developers using SCSS or Less styles, Swiper also provides imports for those files.

For Less styles, replace css with less:
`import 'swiper/swiper.less';`

For SCSS styles replace css with scss: `import 'swiper/swiper.scss';`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. It helped import 'swiper/css'; with React project.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error with svelte and webpack. I was a doing an attempt to update webpack's config.module.rules value. Removing this attempt fixed the error.